# Flyway-ant debug mode details doesnt show db stmts and update counts

Tags: flyway

I'm using flyway-ant 4.0. 
I could see sql stmts and update count , while using -X option in command line mode.
How to get "'updated row count'" in ant debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this issue from their repo](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1174), code supposed to work and is part of Flyway **4.0**.

You will get affected rows counts in the **log file**, the contents would be alike:

```
2016-01-24 22:40:23.417 DEBUG [           main] o.f.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript    : Executing SQL: update employees set i=5 where name='test1'
2016-01-24 22:40:25.145 DEBUG [           main] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : Update Count: 1
2016-01-24 22:40:25.145 DEBUG [           main] o.f.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript    : Executing SQL: delete from employees where i=2
2016-01-24 22:40:25.797 DEBUG [           main] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : Update Count: 1
```

Note, that Flyway logs the update count as soon as *at least one row* was affected.

Please, reference the issue provided for more information, or please, provide more details on what you are doing and what you are getting in result.

Comment: Yes...that's from command line mode.. I'm looking similar way while executing 'ant' mode. Axel  suggested to use -d option to get ant debug output. But I don't see sql stmts and update count in ant debug log